# JIRA Integration with external systems

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I'm working on a POC to automate downstream processes in external systems based on JIRA processes and have hit a wall with the API.  It appears to have great integration for pulling data about tickets out of JIRA and for the ability to externally generate tickets into JIRA.

However I don't see how to trigger external calls as a part of my workflows.  For example if a ticket should be prevented from being routed to the next stage of a workflow without accessing a database to ensure availability of inventory first how could I do that in JIRA?

Based on attributes in the JIRA ticket upon final completion of the workflow we'd like to send a JMS or REST message or possibly update an external database.  Is this possible?

Thanks all in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a "before" check, use a Validator on the Workflow Transition.

I strongly suggest deploying the (free) [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) add-on. There you can implement a ton of things. For example, you'll get a new validator option "Script Validator", where you can specify a [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) script that decides if it lets through the transition or aborts it.

Comment: And post functions can be used to to handle the "upon final completion" part of the question too.

Comment: Thanks Koshinae and Scott.  We're pretty thin on Groovy - would it be possible to use pure Java like a lot of the BPM packages do?

Comment: Dunno, I haven't heard of any, but it does not qualify. In fact, groovy is easy to learn if you know java. http://www.groovy-lang.org/differences.html